# How to implement void OnFragmentInteractionListener?

Tags: java, android

When I launch my app I get following exception:

*java.lang.RuntimeException: com.demo.mtin.mtin.MainActivity must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener*

Can someone help me with this?
What code I need to add in MainActivity and where?

I have two blank fragments: PopularFragment and RatedFragment

**MainActivity bellow:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity    {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String order = sharedPref.getString("order", "popular");
    if (order.equals("popular")) {
        getPopularMovies();
    } else {
        getTopRatedMovies();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // uci i postaviti order -> popular
    Log.d("NESTO", "NESTO-onCreate");
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);



}
 }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {


        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Please provide better information about your problem. I recommend read before [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a pretty straight-forward error message, go for this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PopularFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, RatedFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener { ... 

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }}
```

You must indicate that your activity implement the fragment's interface, then implement it (can be void though).

And have the following in your fragments :

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Comment: I can only import this to one fragment. How to do it for 2 fragments, and how to create onFragmentInteraction?  Thanks:)